# Saving image in database

Tags: database-performance

Is it good to save an image in database with type BLOB?
or save only the path and copy the image in specific directory?

Which way is the best (I mean good performance for the database and the application) and why?

Comment: You can save as a byte array (varbinary)

Comment: yes but I want to know the best way for a good performance. Save the image itself in database or just save its path.

Comment: The path, but there are some subjectivity regarding it. However saving the image in the database means using a lot of it's internal data logic for meaningless storage which is better kept outside. You'd also need a lot of I/O from the database server which is better used elsewhere.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen thnx for your answer but wouldn't i have a problem when i back-up data ?

Comment: Just do a file backup - that's usual procedure for a server anyway :)

Comment: Yes that's what should I do. Now I'm working on a function that backup the data from database in specific file and then backup all images in directory in the same place of the backup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your requirements?

In the vast majority of cases saving the path will be better, simply because of the sheer size of the files compared to the rest of data (bulge the DB by GBs due to image inclusion). Consider adding an indirection, eg. save the path as a name and a reference to a storage resource (eg. a `storage_id` referencing a row in `storages` tables) and the path attached to the 'storage'. This way you can easily move files (copy all files, then update the storage path, rather than update 1MM individual paths).

However, if your requirements include consistent backup/restore and/or disaster recoverability, is often better to store images in the DB. Is not easier, nor more convenient, but is simply going to be *required*. Each DB has its own way of dealing with this problem, eg. in SQL Server you would use a [FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) type which allows remote access via file access API. See [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/) for an example.

Also, a somehow dated but none the less interesting paper on the topic: [To BLOB or Not to BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64525/tr-2006-45.pdf).

Comment: Thnx for your answer.